# How to get Latest Log Stream Name Using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

How do we get the latest log stream name from a given log group using java code.
I have tried many possibilities and still not able to retrieve it.

```
AWSLogs awsLogs = AWSLogsClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)
                .build();

DescribeLogStreamsRequest describeLogStreamsRequest = new DescribeLogStreamsRequest()
    .withLogGroupName("/aws/lambda/a250348-ecndesc-conversion-lambda-reci-euw1-qe");
describeLogStreamsResult = awsLogs.describeLogStreams(describeLogStreamsRequest);
System.out.println(describeLogStreamsResult.getLogStreams());

for(int i =0; i<describeLogStreamsResult.getLogStreams().size(); i++) {
    logStream = describeLogStreamsResult.getLogStreams().get(i).getLastEventTimestamp();
    Date date = new Date(logStream);
    dateList.add(date);         
}
latestDate = Collections.max(dateList);
System.out.println(latestDate);

System.out.println(dateList.indexOf(latestDate));
logStream1 = describeLogStreamsResult.getLogStreams().get(dateList.indexOf(latestDate)).getLogStreamName();

System.out.println(logStream1);
```

Comment: Please share the approach that you already tried

Comment: I have shared my code above. In this approach I'm getting the log streams of a particular Log group and then getting the Last event time stamp of each log stream. 
From that I'm trying to get the latest timestamp and get the log stream to which that belongs

Comment: I'm able to get the logs using this code, but the problem here is that the getLogStreams() function returns only upto 50 log streams and that too in random. So my code is getting the latest log stream from that 50 log streams only. How can I get the latest log stream when there are 100's of log streams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to order your results:

```
DescribeLogStreamsRequest describeLogStreamsRequest = new DescribeLogStreamsRequest()
    .withLogGroupName("/aws/lambda/a250348-ecndesc-conversion-lambda-reci-euw1-qe")
    .withOrderBy(com.amazonaws.services.logs.model.OrderBy.LastEventTime)
    .withDescending(true);
```

This will return first the log stream with the latest event time (and not necessarily the last created). This is how results are presented in AWS console.